# rpmbuild BuildRequires not detecting package built from source

Tags: ruby, rpm, yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build an RPM from a spec file, and the spec file includes the following line:

BuildRequires: ruby

I actually have ruby installed, but I built it and installed it myself from source, rather than from a package.  How do I get the spec file to recognize a custom built package as fulfilling the requirement?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a `custom built package` you have ruby installed from source. RPM spec file `BuildRequires` are about packages.

If you built a ruby package and then installed it that would work.

If you don't have a ruby package, and don't want to create or install one, then you don't want that `BuildRequires` line in your spec file (at least for your local build, you might still want it in the official spec file).